# openstack create image: 'connection aborted.', error(111, 'connection refused')

Tags: image, openstack, devstack

I'd installed the OpenStack by devStack successfully(installed in VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04). 
After that , I can connect to the dashboard by the Chrome browser.

But the first warning jumped out '**Error: Unable to retrieve usage information**' after I logged in.

Then I press 'Project' and it showed '**Error: Unable to retrieve usage information.**'

I found that no matter what I pressed, it always get the messages to inform me that it can't retrieve anything.

And when I press 'image', a page show up with title:
**CommunicationError at /project/images/
Error finding address for http://10.0.1.15:9292/v1/images/detail?sort_key=created_at&sort_dir=desc&limit=1000: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))**

Not sure what's wrong with it. Any help?

Comment: Check your keystone and glance logs. In terminal on the machine running devstack run screen -x stack and navigate to g-api for glance API logs and key for keystone log output. There should be more information there. To navigate through services in screen press "ctrl a n" to go forward, "ctrl a p" for previous, and finally ctrl a " will give you a selection menu of each service.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you restarted the machine? devstack does not recover from reboots. You have to run stack.sh again. It's a little confusing, cause the openstack web dashboard does load, but all of the other services do not so you get all sorts of error.

In general, you can just run stack.sh again. (though you will lose any previously configured cloud resources)